# SmtpClient.SendAsync() and IDisposable in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

At the end of one of my controller methods, I need to loop through a collection and fire off emails based on business rules.

I do not want this process to block the return from the controller, as this is a "fire and forget" type operation and I need the client to be responsive.

The code I am refactoring currently uses `SmtpClient.Send()` inside of a `using ()` block, because `SmtpClient` implements `IDisposable`.

How is this handled with `SendAsync` in MVC?  I am concerned about the SynchronizationContext and potentially not having `Dispose()` being called here.

The code, just prior to the end of the controller method, is simply:

```
client.SendAsync(message, userToken: null);
```

Comment: Dispose is always called in a using block, it compiles down to a try-finally, so regardless of asynchronous or synchronous, Dispose should be executed.

Comment: As per how the `SmtpClient` is implemented it's strongly not recommended to fire and forget - you'll be under high risk to close active connection for mails being sent or even haven't sent yet. Even if you don't call `Dispose` directly it will eventually be called by finalizer when the object is will be collected and you don't know when it may happen. Though, it's bad idea to use fire and forget for async .NET programming in general.

Comment: Also if you await the `SendAsync()` the Client should be responsive. Could you add more code so we can see how you use `SendAsync()`?